# How to call the java jar along with SQL credentials & its parameter in C# winforms?

Tags: c#

How to call the java jar along with `SQL` credentials & its parameter in `C#` winforms? (I have done the report in `Nextreports`, to the integrate the `nextreports`. I am finding the difficulties) Below mentioned is my `PHP`. In `php` code is working fine.

```
 <?php echo '<pre>';               
    $last_line = system('java -jar                                                               "C:\Users\Prakash\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SimplexJava\Simplex_Next_Reports\Si    mplexJava.jar"  PRAKASH-PC sqlserver Simplex_Almuhaisnah3103 SQL2012  192.168.2.50 1433 sa Intuit@321                      "C:\Users\Prakash\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SimplexJava\Simplex_Next_Reports\Rp    t_BillWiseTotal.report" HTML  2015-01-01 00:00:00,2015-10-01 00:00:00',     $retval);
    // Printing additional info
    echo '
    </pre>
    <hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
    <hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
 ?>
```